# How to add querystring values with RedirectToAction method that is pointing to a new Area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Obviously this isn't working:

```
Session.Clear();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { area = "" }, new { timeout = "true" });
```

I want to kill the session and redirect them back to the login page.  I tried using the ViewBag, but since the session gets killed it doesn't seem to be working.

The purpose is to notify the customer the session timed out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { area = "", timeout = "true" });
```

Works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction( "Login", new RouteValueDictionary( 
    new { controller = controllerName, action = "Account", Id = Id } ) );
```

Something like that should work, if you want to set parameters.